# How to store multiple collections to access via indexing

Tags: java, collections

I have multiple collections and I want to add them all in an array or some other collection so I can access them using indexing. I created a LinkedHashMap and stored them in there.

```
static HashSet <Passenger> floor1 = new HashSet<Passenger>();
static HashSet <Passenger> floor2 = new HashSet<Passenger>();
static HashSet <Passenger> floor3 = new HashSet<Passenger>();

static LinkedHashMap floors = new LinkedHashMap();  //what will be the type for this?

public static void main (String[]argv) {

    floors.put(1,floor1);
    floors.put(2,floor2);
    floors.put(3,floor3);

}
```

Now if I want to access one of this collection and add something in it, it doesn't allow me to add anything in it.

```
floors.get(2).add(1);   //this add function does not work
```

What is the best way to stack up collections?

Thank you for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`floors` should have a proper generic type, in this case ideally `Map<Integer, Set<Passenger>>`.